# What is the best Python data structure for named 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, data-structures

I am new to Python. I have two dimensional data. Lets say "Brand" and "Respondent". I want to perform some calculations on this data. For each brand and respondent there is a corresponding rating. ie:

Pepsi -> Respondent 1 -> 8
Coke -> Respondent 3 -> 10

I could store this in a 2D list, but I like to retain the references for the brands and respondent number/name somehow.

What is the best data structure for this?
Perhaps I could look them up as:

```
random_data["Pepsi"][123]
```

or iterate through each respondent and do some math on each brand.

Comment: I think a dictionary is what you are looking for.

Comment: `{Brand1: {respondent: respodent 1, rating:1}, Brand2: {respondent: respodent 2, rating:10}}` Dictionary like this could be efficient way for your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you need to do with the data, dictionaries are a good start:

```
mydict = {"Pepsi": {"respondent": 3, "rating": 8}, "Coke": {"respondent": 3, "rating":10}}
```

You can access it using:

```
mydict["Pepsi"]["rating"]
```